# Filling a select element from the database depending on the value of the chosen option from another select

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I have a 'select' element which takes its data from the MYSQL database, here's the code:

```
<select id="rcorners2" class="courses">
    <option value="1130"> Database</option>
    <option value="110110110"> Web Advance </option>
    ...
</select>
```

The other 'select' element that I want must contain all the section numbers for the selected course.
The query that should be executed to get the section from the MYSQL databse is as follows:

```
SELECT section_number FROM course WHERE course_id = " ";
```

I looked at similar questions but all the answers was to use an onchange() function on the 'first' select element and using an array to fill the second 'select' element. But unfortunately that doesn't work for me here because i have many courses and not the same number of sections for all of the courses, so I have to fill the second 'select' element from the database depending on the value of the option of the first 'select' element.

How to take the value of the first 'select' element and using it in the query which will fill the second 'select' element ??

Comment: So, replace the take-data-from-array part with make-AJAX-request-to-server then.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You did not even ask any actual question here so far, you only told us what you want, and why what you found does not work for you - that isn’t an actual question.

Comment: I just realized that I didn't include my question in the post 

i just updated it @04FS

Comment: You should load content from Ajax, you may read this https://makitweb.com/auto-populate-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax/